# Meaning of "If you go round to the side, you will see that I am"

Tags: meaning

From G.K. Chesterton's Wikipedia page, there is the following anecdote:

> Chesterton was a large man, standing 6 feet 4 inches (1.93 m) and
>   weighing around 21 stone (130 kg; 290 lb). His girth gave rise to a
>   famous anecdote. During World War I a lady in London asked why he was
>   not 'out at the Front'; he replied, 'If you go round to the side, you
>   will see that I am.'

What does "If you go round to the side, you will see that I am [at the front]" mean? I'm not getting the humor...

Comment: You have your answer (in case you didn't realise, when the lady says *the Front* she means *the fighting front[-line] of the **war**), so I hope you won't feel aggrieved that I'm voting to close the question as "Too Localised". It's unlikely any future users will need this particular pun to be explained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lady was asking why he was not fighting in the war. He replied that he was indeed "out at the front" -- meaning (I presume) that he had a big belly, which she could see if she went "round to the side."

Comment: Exactly. His belly "sticks out" at the [front](http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_luvhzxSHyk1qd9a66o1_500.jpg). Think of the old *Alfred Hitchcock Presents" [intro](http://www.austinchronicle.com/binary/a09d/Hitchsilhouette.jpg).